# neo4j cypher set statement with parameter map

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggling to find a definition of how to use the set cypher command with a parameter map

Cheat sheet says use: `SET n = {map}`

I have tried:

```
START n = node(11379)
SET n = {Name: "Random Test Change"}
```

on my server

I get error:-

```
`.' expected but `=' found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why someone voted you down. To do this statement you need to use a parameter (which you can't do in the console).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map parameter could be used like this:

```
String query = "START n = node(11379) SET n = {map}";

Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("Name", "Random Test Change");

Map<String, Object> queryParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
queryParameters.put("map", myMap);

ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabase);
executionResult = engine.execute(query, queryParameters);
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, the issue is that literal maps aren't supported for set yet. That would be cool, and I know it's planned. So for now you have to use a parameter.