# Using Cypher CREATE command with properties map, from Java

Tags: java, scala, neo4j, cypher

I am struggling to create a node in **Neo4J** using **Cypher** from my **Java (Scala)** code. Need help.

I have an application class:

```
case class Team (val name: String,
             val contactEmail: String)
```

and a corresponding jsonifying helper function:

```
def toNodeProperties = {
   ("props" ->
      ("name"           -> name) ~
      ("contactEmail"   -> contactEmail)
   )
} // Using json4s
```

Now, I want to create a Node on a Neo4J instance from an instance of this. So, this is what I have tried:

```
val t = pretty(render(Team("myTeam","team@gmail.com").toNodeProperties))
```

When I print 't', I see this:

```
{
  "props" : {
    "name" : "myTeam",
    "contactEmail" : "team@gmail.com",
  }
}
```

Then, I try to create a statement, thus:

```
val cypherCreateCommand = "CREATE (t:TestEntity  " + t + ")"
val v1 = db.execute(cypherCreateCommand)
```

Runtime expresses its displeasure:

> Invalid input '"': expected whitespace, comment, a property key name,
>   '}', an identifier or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 2, column 3
>   (offset: 26)) "  "props" : {"    ^

I have thought a JSONIfied string as a parameter to CREATE should have been the obvious thing, but it seemingly is not. Can someone please point out the mistake I am making?

Just in case, here is the relevant portion of `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.5</scala.version>
</properties>
```

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
      <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.11</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
      <artifactId>json4s-native_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.11</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>nscala-time_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  // .... and the rest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - you should use `GraphDatabaseService::execute(String query, Map<String, Object> params)` method, if you have parametrized query

Using this method (instead of string concatenation) give possibility Neo4j to more efficiently compile query and then reuse it.

---

For your case I believe this should work:

(I am not strong in Scala, that why this is Java code. But, I think it should be self-explanatory)

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("props", new HashMap<String, Object>() {
    add("name", name);
    add("contactEmail", contactEmail);
});

String query = "CREATE (t:TestEntity  {props})"
db.execute(query, params);
```

Note: I have not tested this code.

What we have been done:

- Create `params` container
- Put `props` map into `params` container
- Write `query` with special placeholder (similar to prepared statements in relational DB)
- Execute `query` with specified `params`

**EDIT** (by @Nirmalya): [detailed description about cypher parameters from neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html).

Comment: You were too quick for me! :-) Before I could find the mistake I was making and came back to provide the answer, you had been here, and shared the _right_ answer. Two mistakes: (a) not using the 2nd parameter with executeQuery and and (b) missed the point that the string _props_ must be the key of the top-level Map. Because of the way examples are given here [link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html), I assumed a JSON-like structure would be acceptable.

Comment: I also happened to stumble upon [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439414/neo4j-cypher-set-statement-with-parameter-map) which suggested the same thing. I understood where I was going wrong. However, I must add that this scheme is somewhat  *unintuitive* and *cumbersome*!

Comment: I am wondering why can't a JSON-like formation - which honours the same *Map-of-a-Map* structure - be used?

Comment: It can be. But it's not best way to do this. Cypher compiles query to Java bytecode. If params are used - then query is compiled to "paramterized" version. This gives possibility to reuse this compiled query version with different set of parameters. If you use JSON-like format, then compiler should compile query every time.

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional comma after the email address.

```
{
  "props" : {
    "name" : "myTeam",
    "contactEmail" : "team@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, thanks for pointing that out. Even otherwise, Neo4J Cypher APIs don't find JSON palatable, as I have found out. :-) So, a correct JSON would not have mattered really!